# c# get all properties in classProperty

Tags: c#, list, properties

I have a List and I would like to know how much Properties are in each Item List.
Like the following example code I got four 'items' String in my Property class and I want to add it to a listview.

The problem is that I can't enumerate my property class Items as they are not a list. so I would like to count String Items in Property and then increment a variable to add it to the listview.

The main point is that my properties can be of any type (String, int and so on) and I would like to do a generic code for that.

Thanks in advance.

Code classList

```
public static class mylistitems
    {
       // public static List<Properties> mylistprop = new List<Properties>();
        public static List<Properties> createdata(String name, String surname, String friend, String pet)
        {
            var DataProperties = new List<Properties>();
            DataProperties.Add(new Properties { Name = name, SurName = surname, Friend = friend, Pet = pet });
            return DataProperties;
        }
        public class Properties
        {
            public String Name { get; set; }
            public String SurName { get; set; }
            public String Friend { get; set; }
            public String Pet { get; set; }
        }
    }
```

Code Caller

```
 List<mylistitems.Properties>  newlistitem = mylistitems.createdata("Derrick","Thomas","giordino","Max");
      foreach (mylistitems.Properties propertyitem in newlistitem)
      {
          //Here!! Is it possible to get all the properties in a loop
                        ListViewItem LVitem = new ListViewItem();
          LVitem.SubItems.Add(propertyitem.Name);
          LVitem.SubItems.Add(propertyitem.SurName);
          LVitem.SubItems.Add(propertyitem.Friend);
          LVitem.SubItems.Add(propertyitem.Pet);
          //how to change it like something like this
          foreach (String item in propertyitem)
          { LVitem.SubItems.Add(item); }
      }
```

Comment: No, I think that adding it manually is correct. You add each property to the list view as your desired order.

Comment: what you do here is actually correct way. You can do it by using reflection but it will cost you with performance issues. I know it looks like kinda dirty stuff.